# Remove Bootstrap whitespace below nav navbar-nav

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to remove the bootstrap whitespace between my menu and the following section.  My menu **HTML** is:

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <ul class="navbar-brand">
                    <li><a href="/"><img src="{% static 'img/apps-png.png' %}" width="150px" alt="appsrfun logo" /></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                  <li><a href="{% url 'home' %}">Home</a></li>
                  <li><a href="{% url 'home' %}">Mobile Apps</a></li>
                  <li><a href="{% url 'home' %}">Android</a></li>
                  <li><a href="{% url 'home' %}">Apple</a></li>
                  <li><a href="{% url 'home' %}">Download</a></li>
                  <li><a href="{% url 'home' %}">Tags</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div><!-- .container -->
    </nav>
```

If I inspect each element the bottom border, padding and margin are all set to 0px.  There is a mysterious white space between the end of `<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">` and the end of `<ul class="nav navbar-nav">`.  The former has a shows a height of 106px while the latter shows 100px but neither has border, margin or padding.  How do I align them?

Thanks

EDIT

I've included my **CSS** to remove the bootstrap standard margins and padding

```
/* Navbar */
.navbar .navbar-nav {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
}

.navbar .navbar-collapse {
    text-align: center;
}

.navbar .nav > li > a:link, .navbar .nav > li > a:visited {
    color: #f7931e;
    height: 100px;
    padding-top: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.navbar .nav > li > a:hover, .navbar .nav > li > a:active {
    background-color: #f7931e;
    color: #ffffff;
    border-bottom: 6px solid #ffff01;
}

.navbar {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
}

.navbar-brand {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.navbar-default {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: You are having margin-bottom of 20px on the <nav> tag and margin-bottom of 10px on the <ul> with class 'navbar-brand'.

Comment: @VasilIndzhev I've added my CSS to show I've covered that

Comment: Have you .wrap or .wrap >.container  in you css ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probrably it has to do with the **vertical-align**. try setting **vertical-align:middle** to **.navbar .navbar-nav**.

***Edit:*** Usually that happens when you have elements with different vertical-align values. I don't know what are the CSS for the rest of your code but, having elementA with vertical-align:middle and elementB vertical-align:baseline.

Example:

```css
.container{min-height:80px;width:100%;background:#333;}
.box1{background:#eee;width:40px;height:40px;display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle;}
.box2{background:red;width:100px;height:100px;display:inline-block;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box1"></div>
  <div class="box2"></div>
</div>
```

Setting vertical-align:middle to .box2, will fix the problem.

Comment: Added an explanation, hopefully it makes sense now. :)